# What's the proper style to write a company's name followed by Inc?

Tags: writing, abbreviations

> **Facebook, Inc.
>
> Google Inc. 
>
> Twitter, Inc.
>
> Apple Inc.**

This is what I read on Wikipedia about [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook), [Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google), [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) and [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_inc). Note that the first and third has **comma before Inc.**. The second and fourth has **no comma** again.

**The question -**

Which one is the correct style to write a company's name followed by Inc.? Is comma necessary to put after company's name and before Inc.?

I think there should be a strict rule as it deals with company's registration where punctuation marks do play an essential role.

Can a check put in the name of Twitter, Inc. get declined if it's registered as Twitter Inc.?

Your view please.

Answer (score 1):

A name is simply whatever it is. Some names have "the", some don't. Some names have commas, some don't. Some names have odd capitalization, some don't. Oddly, Facebook sometimes [uses a comma](https://www.facebook.com/payments_terms/privacy) and sometimes [doesn't](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy), so they may not have actually decided what their name is.

Comment: According to one movie, Facebook was almost even named "The Facebook". ;-)

Comment: When it comes to the legal documents, I think a persistent style is preferred. A check put in the name of Facebook, Inc. may get declined if they find the company name Facebook Inc. as registered.

Comment: The legal name is [definitely](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000119312512325997/d371464d10q.htm) "FACEBOOK, INC."

Comment: Checking with SEC is a great idea. For example, according to this [document](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1418091/000119312513390321/d564001ds1.htm), we can be sure that Twitter's legal name is "Twitter, Inc." ;-)

Comment: And also "APPLE INC." [[1](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312512444068/d411355d10k.htm)], and "GOOGLE INC." [[2](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000119312504073639/ds1.htm)].

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Capitalization and punctuation has no meaning in legal names (you can see that in this [SEC filing](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000119312512034517/d287954ds1.htm), the legal name of Facebook is *also* exactly "Facebook, Inc", even though in your document you link to it is "FACEBOOK, INC"), whereas at [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaq.com/quotes/insiders/zuckerberg-mark-882215) it is usually called "FACEBOOK INC"

Comment: The "proper" American style is to put the comma. That has been deteriorating, possibly in part because the British style is to not put a comma before "Ltd.", the British equivalent to Inc., possibly because postal conventions are to remove punctuation from addresses, and possibly because it simply isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

From an English standpoint, it is a matter of preference.

From a style standpoint, it is also a matter a preference.

From a legal standpoint, whatever is filed with the Secretary of State is the official name of the company. It is whatever is stated in the Articles of Incorporation or Articles of Organization.

If they registered with a comma, then legally, the company name must always have a comma in it. Likewise, if they registered without a comma, the company name should always be written without a comma. This is especially true of contracts and legal documents where punctuation matters.

When you form your company as a corporation or an LLC, you get to choose whether you use a comma or not. But that decision is permanent.

In the U.S., most companies put a comma before Inc., Corp., Ltd., or LLC, but some companies are opting for the British style with no commas.

When writing about a company, ideally, you should use their actual legal name, whether that be with a comma or without.

Personally, it is a huge red flag if someone writing about a company can't even get the name of the company right. What else do they have wrong in their article? And on an application, getting the name wrong is an indicator of possible fraud, because the owners of the company would know whether there is suppose to be a comma or not.

In the end, it does not matter whether you use a comma in the company name. It is a matter of preference. But once the company is registered, it must use the name it registered.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that varies by style. For example, much to my surprise, this major style guide says no comma:

> According to AP Style you **do not** use a comma before “Inc.” or “Ltd.,” even if it is included in the formal name. — [Writing Explained](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-company-names)